# Remove the /bin folder from repository sync

Tags: java, mercurial, repository, tortoisehg

I am working with BitBucket online repository. i opened a new repository and synced some folder (with tortoisehg) on my computer, then opened an eclipse project inside that folder.

Now when i want to commit, the /bin folder is being synced as well...
obviously i don't want that to happen, all i want is to sync the /src and the /test.

Can someone please help me with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a .hgignore file to your root directory and then manually remove anything which got added before the .hgignore file was created or synced to the local repository.

If you just want to ignore /bin at the top level (ignore directory and contents), add the line:

```
^bin$
```

If you want to ignore the contents of /bin at the top level (include directory, ignore contents, add the line:

```
^bin/
```

If you want to ignore all directories name bin, add the line:

```
/bin$
```

If you want to ignore the contents of all directories named bin (but keep the directory), add the line:

```
/bin/
```

If you want to ignore some of the contents of all directories named bin, add a line like:

```
/bin/.*\.o$
```

By default, it uses regular expression syntax.  If you'd rather use glob syntax, you can add a line which changes the syntax for all following lines:

```
syntax: glob
```

So, to ignore all files in a root directory named bin, you could alternately add:

```
syntax: glob
/bin/*
```

Here's the [man page](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html) about hgignore files.

Comment: Works like a charm. Grate answer.

Comment: You still have to manually remove anything which got added before the .hgignore file was added.  Use `hg remove` to remove files from source control and delete them.  Use `hg forget` to remove things without deleting.  Also, for remote repositories, make sure that the update with the .hgignore file is applied before doing adds.